# How do I make the colorbar of my image plot in matlab to get discrete values without only giving colour to parts of my data

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am plotting a matrix with rain intensities with an image plot in matlab.

I want the colorbar to show a distinct colour for 0-10, 10-20... to 90-10.

I've tried the function `surf(10)` to get 10 discrete colors, but then only values up 10 is showed.

This is the code I used:

```
image(pr20020719T0730)
cmap = jet(10);
colormap(cmap);
colorbar
```

This is how the image looks after the code

[image]

Comment: Check out the [`caxis()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) function

Answer (score 4):

Unlike `imshow`, the `image` function sets the `CDataMapping` property of the image object to `'direct'`. Read MATLAB [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.image-properties.html) for more details. This is how this affects the outcome:

```matlab
% create 256x256-matrix with discrete, ascending column values
X = repmat(linspace(0, 100, 256), 256, 1);
% first subplot
subplot 121
image(X)
colorbar
% second subplot
subplot 122
image(X, 'CDataMapping', 'scaled')
colorbar

% set colormalt to "jet"
cmap = jet(10);
colormap(cmap)
```

[image]